# Preview custom text in fonts.google.com by URL

Tags: url, google-fonts

Occasionally found this type of link (Google Fonts Previewer undocumented feature?) - search with query:

```
https://fonts.google.com/selection?query=some+search+text&selection.family=Archivo+Black|Asul|Cardo
```

It gives a list of fonts, but preview-test-text must be entered in the input box.

Is it possible to put custom text in URL (i.e. basically - to generate a preview with the link) to view how it looks in https://fonts.google.com/?

Maybe some kind of:

```
https://fonts.google.com/selection?query=search+text&selection.family=Archivo+Black|Asul|Cardo&preview=Some+Custom+Text+for+Preview
```

Comment: this is not possible to achieve and also its unwise for google to provide such "luxury" coz it would bloat them

Comment: @user0 please put this comment into the aswers - this probably the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible to achieve and also it's unwise for Google to provide such "luxury" coz it would bloat them

Answer (score 0):

Use the following URL parameter:

```
?preview.text_type=custom&preview.text=1234567890
```